# How to use groupby or aggreation in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

here is the exemple

```
[A]
XXXX
SSSS
[B]
EEEEE
EEEEE
[A]
ZZZZ
RRRR
[B]
TTTTT
UUUUU
[C]
OOOOO
ZZZZZ
```

the question is how can we do in linux shell groupby element to have this result ? :

```
[A]
XXXX
SSSS
ZZZZ
RRRR
[B]
EEEEE
EEEEE
TTTTT
UUUUU
[C]
OOOOO
ZZZZZ
```

So if can have a function or script or set of commands to do this task that would help me a lot in my project of auto proxy and load balancers. Thank you

Comment: Anyway, use awk to create an array that's keyed by the section labels.

Comment: i did a mistake

Comment: B also must be grouped

Comment: So click the Edit link and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '
/^\[/ {
  group = $0
  next
}
{
  elems[group] = elems[group] $0 ORS
}
END {
  for (group in elems)
    printf "%s%s%s", group, ORS, elems[group]
}' file
```